# How to get list of installed packages for a specific user

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server

How can I list all the packages that a specific user installed?
Given that I have sudo/root permission.

Comment: Users don't install deb packages. Admins do. Apt neither logs nor tracks which admin ordered a particular action.

Comment: /var/log/auth.log will track which admin ordered a particular action, but only as far back as those logs go.